# How to restrict Play store's Publishing API based on IP Address?

Tags: android, api, google-play, continuous-deployment, google-play-developer-api

We are going to implement **continuous integration** for alpha release in play store. I refereed the playstore's documentation and github project for releasing APKs via API. But I didn't find the security mechanism for restricting the Release API to be used by only the permitted IP address. How to restrict the Release API based on ip address?

Referred the [Google's best practice documentation](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037?hl=en) for securing the API access. They also suggested to restrict the API acccess based on IP Address.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You configure the IP addresses when creating an API key. The list of allowed addresses is tied to the key you use for authenticating.

- On https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials, click "Create credentials", "API key".
- The key appears. Click "Restrict key" to immediately go to the editing screen.
- Under "Application restrictions", select "IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.)".
- Under "Accept requests from these server IP addresses", add the IP address(es) of your server(s).
- Recommended: under "API restrictions", select "Restrict key" and select only the Release API. (I don't see it in the list, but maybe I don't have it enabled for this particular project.)
- Click "Save".

See also documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?visit_id=636955837922702973-2281839130&rd=1#securing_an_api_key) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions).